# More Efficient Way of List Function and Questioning/Answering?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm Making A troubleshooter, for my GCSE which gives an appropriate answer based on the users input. My original code was:

```
keywords = ["k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6","k7","k8","k9","kk"]

question_about_phone = input("What Seems to be the Problem? Please be percific but don't bombard us with too much info").lower()

file = open('code.txt','r')
solution = [line.strip(',') for line in file.readlines()]

for x in range(0, 10):
    if keywords[x] in question_about_phone:
        print(solution[x])
```

However what happened was my teacher told me i cant stack solutions, e.g. k1 and k3 together cant end up with the k1 and k3 solution merged but have to put an individual solution.

Because of this, this is what i've done:

```
keywords = ["k1","k2","k3","k4","k5","k6","k7","k8","k9","kk"]
true = ["False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False","False"]
question_about_phone = input("What Seems to be the Problem? Please be percific but don't bombard us with too much info").lower()
file = open('code.txt','r')
solution = [line.strip(',') for line in file.readlines()]

for x in range(0, 10):
    if keywords[x] in question_about_phone:
        true == "true"

if true[1] == "true" and true[2] == "true" and true[3] == "true":
    print(solution[1])

if true[1] == "true" and true[3] == "true" and true[5] == "true":
    print(solution[2])

if true[1] == "true" and true[7] == "true" and true[8] == "true":
    print(solution[3])

if true[8] == "true" and true[4] == "true" and true[5] == "true":
    print(solution[4])

if true[6] == "true" and true[9] == "true" and true[4] == "true":
    print(solution[5])

if true[3] == "true" and true[4] == "true" and true[8] == "true":
    print(solution[6])

if true[1] == "true" and true[9] == "true" and true[2] == "true":
    print(solution[7])

if true[10] == "true" and true[1] == "true" and true[9] == "true":
    print(solution[8])

if true[3] == "true" and true[7] == "true" and true[10] == "true":
    print(solution[9])

if true[7] == "true" and true[3] == "true" and true[4] == "true":
    print(solution[10])
```

Now is there any way to simplify this or do I have to leave it like this. Would really appreciate it, Thank you

Comment: A side note: I think you mean `please be specific` rather than `please be percific`.

Comment: You should ask at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). There, the format will be particularly well suited for your kind of question and you will most probably get better help.

Comment: Instead of deleting the content from your question, you should just delete the question. Although, if Darth Kotik's answer helped, you should accept it

Comment: @Kay - I'm not at all, if the question is no longer relevant then they should delete it, however since this was an attempt at "taking their ball back home with them" I've edited my comment.

Comment: discussed at MSO: [User keeps deleting own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/316368/839601)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's possible to use some dictionary to store solutions:

```
solutions = {
    solution[1]: [1, 2, 3], 
    solution[2]: [1, 3, 5],
    solution[3]: [1, 7, 8], 
    ...
}
```

So you can do something like this

```
for answer, questions in solutions.items():
    if all([true(x)=="true" for x in questions]):
        print answer
        break
```